# What are fish racks for?

Tags: core-keeper

In the Sunken Depths area, you can find fish net racks. They look like a drying rack, they're place-able furniture, and you can store 3 fish in them. The rack visibly shows the fish that are inside it. When you destroy one in the wild, a fish or two usually drop out.

But, after placing one in a base and filling it with fish, I do not see it having an effect on the fish. Maybe it just takes a long time though. What do they do?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this fish rack just *holds* fish and does anything else. This is probably why it is called a fish rack, which usually holds fish in place to cook in real life.